# Vary: User-Agent in case of redirect?

Tags: seo, google, http-headers

Should we use `Vary: User-Agent` in our headers when the regular URL `www.example.com` is forwarded to `m.example.com`? Or is it not needed for Google due to the redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use vary header if you dynamically change the content for specific devices on the same URL depending on the user agent.

You can see this outlined here: [Google guide on Dynamic Serving](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/dynamic-serving)

If you use separate URLs for mobile you do not need to use the vary header. You should however tell Google the relationship between two URLs by tagging them with the rel="canonical" (on mobile URLs) and rel="alternate" (on the mobile pages) elements.

You can see this outlined here: [Google guide Separate Mobile URLs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/separate-urls)

Comment: Using the User-Agent to determine if a page redirects **is** dynamically changing the content.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the user agent to determine if `www.example.com` serves content or is redirected to `m.example.com`, then you should use `Vary: User-Agent`.

You don't need to use the `Vary: User-Agent` heading if you have separate mobile and desktop sites without any redirects between them.  You could also implement the redirects client side in JavaScript.  Then the server would serve the same content to all user agents.

The reason that the `Vary: UserAgent` header is needed is for any caching proxy servers.  You might want to use a caching CDN for your site.   Some corporate networks and ISPs use caching proxy servers between their users and your website.

If you don't use the `Vary: User-Agent` header, then the following might happen:

- A mobile user requests the site from the proxy server.
- The proxy server doesn't have the site cached and requests it from your server.
- Your server looks at the user agent and returns a redirect.
- The proxy server caches the redirect and returns it to the mobile device.
- A desktop user requests the site from the same proxy server.
- The proxy server responds with the cached redirect.

If you had been using the `Vary: User-Agent` header, then the proxy server would make a request to your server for every different user agent.   Redirects wouldn't get returned to the wrong devices.